# Mongodb events.js:85

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, mongodb

I am working on this project since long. I am facing some problem which I am unable to solve after trying really hard. I would really appreciate if you guys can help me. I am trying to connect to mongodb database using node.js but whenever I start server I get following error. And I have no idea how to solve that error.

```html
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
The magic happens on port 8080
Connected correctly to server
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Apps\linked-up 0.0.1\easy-node-authentication-master\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:556:74)
    at emit (events.js:118:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Apps\linked-up 0.0.1\easy-node-authentication-master\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Apps\linked-up 0.0.1\easy-node-authentication-master\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:534:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at net.js:950:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Thank you for your time and consideration

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are up and running mongodb locally in the system ?

To map local path to mongodb try the following command

[location of mongodb]/bin/ **mongod --dbpath "specify location of database"**

Answer (score 0):

Do you write you code like below?

`mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to database`

I guess you did't set your configDB.url .

set it with your db url like `'localhost:27017/myDatabase'`